# CVPR Style in draft mode fails to compile pstricks figure

Tags: pdftex, pstricks

I'm new to this pstricks figures. So I apologize if my question is very basic.

So this is the problem. I have a style from CVPR, [cvpr.sty](http://pastebin.com/NBsefUd3), and a figure that I create using a [script](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25298) that creates figures from MATLAB using pstricks. So I have my figure [fig1.tex](http://pastebin.com/4Zr9ZMcB), which I intend to include in a document like this example:

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
 \usepackage{cvpr}

 \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
 \usepackage{pst-node, pst-plot, pst-circ}
 \usepackage{moredefs}

 \cvprfinalcopy % Comment this line and it stop working! :(
 \ifcvprfinal\pagestyle{empty}\fi

 \begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
 \input{fig1.tex}
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

However, if I enable the draft mode by commenting the `\cvprfinalcopy` it stops working and I obtain the error

```
MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.00: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

I think that there is some problem with the draft mode and the numbers it adds. Because in final mode the figure is generated and I get no error. However, I'm new to pstricks, so I have no idea where to look.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

PS. I paste the files in other site, I'm not sure if that is OK, or if I should paste them in this same question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-plot, pst-circ}
\usepackage{moredefs}

\usepackage{CVPR}
\def\cvprPaperID{}
%\cvprfinalcopy % Comment this line and it stop working! :(
\ifcvprfinal\pagestyle{empty}\fi

 \begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
 \input{fig1.tex}
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

Change the loading order of the packages and define a paper ID if it is not a final paper!

Comment: Thanks! that worked. I never thought about changing the order of the packages. Can you explain me why this happens?
PS. I have the ID in the original, but in here I omitted because I thought it was irrelevant. Thanks for the advice.