# EveryShipout errors when using TikZ with conference style

Tags: tikz-pgf, eso-pic

Using the conference style `cvpr.sty` from the [CVPR 2013 Author Kit](http://www.pamitc.org/cvpr13/files/cvpr2013AuthorKit.zip), the following small example works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cvpr}
\def\cvprPaperID{0}   % necessary for cvpr.sty to work

%\usepackage{tikz}    % uncommenting this line results in errors

\begin{document}
  test
\end{document}
```

although I get the warning

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `eso-pic', but the package provides `everyshi'.
```

However, if I uncomment `\usepackage{tikz}`, I get lots of errors related to EveryShipout, the first one being

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \@EveryShipout@Hook already defined.
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue? It seems to be related to the warning about `eso-pic` and `everyshi` but I don't know how.

(I have seen [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31199/), but the solution - reordering the packages - doesn't work here.)

Comment: Hmm. They are providing a hacked `eso-pic.sty` themselves, based on a very old version of `eso-pic`, that loads a hacked `everyshi` in a wrong way. My suggestion is to tell them to remove the hacked `eso-pic.sty`.

Comment: Ah, indeed: After deleting the provided `eso-pic.sty` it works! Since LaTeX now uses the standard (non-hacked) `eso-pic`: Are there any substantial differences in their hacked version, i.e., will the output now be different?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. But, as far as I know, the final behavior of `eso-pic` didn't change from the old version to the new.

Comment: Why was this question closed? I have the exact same error here and found it through Google.

Comment: @Ben It was closed because the problem is in the 'CVPR 2013 Author Kit', which is doing something it should not do. That code is not generally distributed (not on CTAN, in TeX Live or MiKTeX), so it's 'localized'.

Comment: I still think an answer to this question could have been helpful. This question was the #1 Google hit. Our only disagreement is the word "too" in "too localized".

Comment: I don't think it is too localized too. I am having the exact same problem at the moment.

Comment: @nimcap As I said in my first comment, I simply deleted the `eso-pic.sty` from the author kit to let LaTeX use the standard version. I didn't notice any changes - except that I could now use `tikz`. :)

Comment: I am also having the same problem and it's not the first time. Deleting `eso-pic.sty` works, so I've probably done this again in the past. More than 1000 people submit papers to CVPR every year, and the issue remains. So this question + solution are definitely useful.

Comment: One year later, same problem, same solution, same place :-)

Comment: Same issue seems to be affecting ICCV 2015 kit. But same "solution in the comments" seems to apply too :P.

Comment: Same problem here. Removing the author kit eso, changes the output for me...

Comment: Thanks. Had the same Problem and the comments here (deleting eso-pic.sty) solved it.

Comment: It's 2017 and the ICCV template it's still suffering from this.

Comment: I'm surprised no one solved this yet. In the case of the ICCV template, this is simply caused by the fact that `eso-pic.sty` (which is included in `iccv.sty`) includes `iccv_eso.sty` (which actually provides the package `everyshi`) with the `\input` command. **In order to solve this:** rename `iccv_eso.sty` to `everyshi.sty`; and replace the line `\input{iccv_eso.sty}` with `\usepackage{everyshi}` (at the beginning of `eso-pic.sty`).

Comment: @Sheljohn, that didn't help resolve the warning. Now I have a warning the other way around! `LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `everyshi', but the package provides `eso-pic'.`

Comment: @Amir I think you must have renamed `eso-pic` instead of `iccv_eso`.. try re-reading my comment.

Comment: I just commented \input{cvpr_eso.sty} in eso-pic.sty to make it work

Comment: @Alex, commenting `\input{cvpr_eso.sty}` itself doesn't solve it and raise a compilation error. @Shelijohn, I did rename `cvpr_eso.sty` and changed the include line to point to that and the warning did not resolved. Whatever, it is a meaningless warning

Comment: I can confirm that @Sheljohn's solution works for CVPR. Simply removing `eso-pic.sty` will make building "review submission" fail.

Comment: You don't need to use the old versions of the packages on `cvpr.sty` or `iccv.sty`.  You need to delete the old versions of the `eso-pic.sty` (and `cvpr_eso.sty` since it won't be needed), and use the newer versions.  You will get an error on due to the `\kern` operations on `cvpr.sty` but that can be fixed with dimension operations.  A fixed version can be found here https://gitlab.com/snippets/1761648.

Comment: 33 upvotes on this question. Still "an extraordinarily narrow situation"? You sure?

Comment: It's 2021! Nine years later, CVPR/ICCV have taken a different course, requiring a new solution. But the same problem persists in WACV, where the same old solution applies!

Comment: It's 2022. We have amazing things like ChatGPT but the CVPR template is still broken. My document with Tikz figures would only compile with Texlive 2022. To make it work with Texlive 2020 (used by Arxiv) I followed this simple fix: https://github.com/MCG-NKU/CVPR_Template/issues/3#issue-720949477