# ./wacv_eso.sty:0: You have requested package `eso-pic', but the package provides `everyshi'

Tags: compiling

I cannot compile the [wacv 2019 author kit](http://wacv19.uccs.us/wp-content/uploads/wacv2019-author-kit.zip).
Before this question gets closed or voted down for being "too narrow" consider the comments to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76314/122867) similar question. Conference templates that don't compile are a problem for potentially ~1k people.

Comment: Can you please add a source for the author kit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently one solution is to replace line 26 in `eso-pic.sty` from

```
\input{wacv_eso.sty}
```

to

```
\usepackage{everyshi}
```

Then one needs to download the file `everyshi.sty` for example from github [here](https://github.com/chiamingyen/extensions/blob/master/extensions/portableLatex/MiKTeX/texmf/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty) and place it in the same folder as the `eso-pic.sty` file.

Comment: `\input{wacv_eso.sty}` is always wrong.

Answer (score 7):

The author kit contains a rogue `eso-pic.sty` based on a *very* old version of the package (2002/11/16 v1.1b). To make a comparison, TeX Live 2012 ended its life with `eso-pic.sty`  2010/10/06 v2.0c`.

Also, this obsolete version is further modified by adding the line

```
\input{wacv_eso.sty}
```

which is wrong.

Besides, `wacv_eso.sty` appears to be a straight copy of `everyshi.sty`, including

```
\ProvidesPackage{everyshi}
         [2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)]
```

which is the cause for the warning.

It's been a while since `eso-pic` dropped requiring `everyshy` and favored `atbegshi`.

The solution of changing `\input{wacv_eso.sty}` into `\RequirePackage{everyshi}` is effective.

The main package `wacv.sty` features a funny header, where something very strange appears:

```
% with LaTeX2e:
% =============
%
% use as
%   \documentclass[times,10pt,twocolumn]{article}
%   \usepackage{latex8}
%   \usepackage{times}
%
% ---------------------------------------------------------------

% with LaTeX 2.09:
% ================
%
% use as
%   \documentstyle[times,art10,twocolumn,latex8]{article}
%
% ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

LaTeX2.09 has been obsolete for about 25 years. The call for `\usepackage{latex8}` will raise an error, as the package is not included in the main TeX distributions and, indeed, the example TeX file *doesn't* load it. Also `times` has been obsolete for more than 20 years and `mathptmx` should be used (there is better support for Times nowadays, though).

Other funny pieces:

```
\font\wacvtenhv  = phvb at 8pt % *** IF THIS FAILS, SEE wacv.sty ***
\font\elvbf  = ptmb scaled 1100
```

Using `\font` directly in LaTeX has been deprecated since the release of LaTeX2e in 1994.

The maintainers of the author kit should do better than just changing the year.